# Set a content-typ in eclipse infocenter for *.xsd files?

Tags: eclipse, xsd

We have a java server running an eclipse infocenter. The setup is standard; pretty much according to [the help](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ua_help_setup_infocenter.htm). One of our plugin helps have links to a XSD file and we want to be able to display that. The problem is that the XSD schema is shown as text/plain instead of text/xml.

How can we set the content type of the filetypes?

**Edit:** 
The infocenter requires the plugins:

```
org.apache.lucene
org.eclipse.core.runtime
org.eclipse.help
org.eclipse.help.appserver
org.eclipse.help.base
org.eclipse.help.webapp
org.eclipse.osgi
org.eclipse.tomcat
org.eclipse.update.configurator
```

So I'm guessing the server is a tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer to this problem is that there is a file in the Jetty server that determines how to handle different filetype. For `*.xsd` it is defaulted to text/plain.

The solution was to decompile `org.mortbay.jetty*.jar`, change the file `mime.properties` by adding `xsd   = application/xml` at the end. And then recompiling it again.

Piece of cake. Only took two years to find out :)

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm not exactly sure about your setup, adding a dependency on `org.eclipse.wst.xsd.ui` would add the XSD editor to an Eclipse application in general.